# How can I find RPG designers in my area?

Tags: game-design, finding-other-players

For an event in the far future, my Dutch games society would like to invite a few local (in this case western Netherlands or possibly BeNeLux) RPG designers to come to us, play their games with us and talk about them. Our FLGS stocks games of one indie publisher living in the city (and I have some contact details), and at a small local convention last year we met another designer living in the larger region, but beyond that I'm stumped for ways to start looking.

There is no Indie-Meetup in town to ask around and maybe even have the chance that local designers might turn up there. For meetups elsewhere in Holland, I don't know how to find and know what's useful.

RPGGeek.com has a huge list of designers, but it's not possible to search through them. The “Designer” search does not go through the full-text of their description, and many people don't have a listed location.

Dutch is generally a small language and games rarely translated into it, so I cannot pilfer the Dutch-language section on DrivethruRPG for appropriate publishers and continue searching from there.

So, how do I find RPG designers from (roughly) the Netherlands and northern Belgium?

Comment: Point of order:  RPGGeek's advanced search does go through full text search.

Here's the result of searching for 'Dutch':  https://rpggeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=itemdescription&q=Dutch&B1=Go&subtypes%5B%5D=rpgdesigner

Here's the result of searching for 'Netherlands':  https://rpggeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=itemdescription&q=Netherlands&B1=Go&subtypes%5B%5D=rpgdesigner

'Holland' is a bit less useful since it's a common surname.

But yeah, if you want to do a full-text search, just choose Advanced Search.

Comment: @sgfit That seems less like a point of order and more a working solution. I encourage you to make that into an answer post.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question asked, just an offhanded comment about how to use a website, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Meetup.com](https://www.meetup.com) will allow you to create a meet up in your area. It worked well for me in the San Francisco Bay Area for a variety of issues, and they do have a Netherlands region. iOS developers, kids play groups, graphic artists, dog play groups; those are types of things I used it for. I couldn't imagine game designers not having a presence on meetup.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on your answer? Did it work well for you in the SF Bay area *to find game designers*, or just in general?

Comment: It worked for a variety of issues. iOS developers, kids play groups, graphic artists, dog play groups; Those are types of things I used it for. I couldn't imagine game designers not having a presence on meet up

Comment: I didn't find a designer meetup, but I found a Dutch designer using the general Dutch RPG Guild on meetup.com

Answer (score -1):

I think you are on the right track by speaking with people at conventions.  A big problem with indie games is lack of publicity so outside of networking (talking to people) there not a lot of ways to find them in your local area.

The second thing I would do is get on some indie rpg forums and ask around there.  Places like [The Forge Forums](http://www.indie-rpgs.com/forge/index.php) or [Indie RPGWatch](https://www.rpgwatch.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=49) or maybe even [RPG Net](https://forum.rpg.net/forum.php).  This could take time but may be the next best thing to going to conventions.

Finally, while searching a bit on the subject I found a [question from 2012](http://www.story-games.com/forums/discussion/17455/indy-rpg-publishers-in-germany-netherland) that was on game designers in the Netherlands. There are several answers that could be of use to you.